# How to perform uploading of data which could be audio, text or image in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an audio file in android to a server. The problem is that I have no idea how to write upload code in Android or if there are any libraries or API that I can use.

I am new to Android development with no experience of server side. I have very little knowledge of how to connect and communicate with a server, post data to server, fetch data from server and what responses to look for from the server.

I am trying to find to find a tutorial or a guide which can show how to upload in Android and also explain what is being done in the code. Any guide or suggestions on how to learn to communicate with server would be very helpful.

Comment: to achieve this functionality you can use AsyncTask in android

Answer (score 0):

Use this code using volley for network requests to upload text, multipart(audio, image, etc) :

```
String url = "http://yoururl.com";
        VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String resultResponse = new String(response.data);
                try {
                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(resultResponse);
                    String status = result.getString("status");
                    String message = result.getString("message");

                    if (status.equals(Constant.REQUEST_SUCCESS)) {
                        // tell everybody you have succed upload image and post strings
                        Log.i("Messsage", message);
                    } else {
                        Log.i("Unexpected", message);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                String errorMessage = "Unknown error";
                if (networkResponse == null) {
                    if (error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)) {
                        errorMessage = "Request timeout";
                    } else if (error.getClass().equals(NoConnectionError.class)) {
                        errorMessage = "Failed to connect server";
                    }
                } else {
                    String result = new String(networkResponse.data);
                    try {
                        JSONObject response = new JSONObject(result);
                        String status = response.getString("status");
                        String message = response.getString("message");

                        Log.e("Error Status", status);
                        Log.e("Error Message", message);

                        if (networkResponse.statusCode == 404) {
                            errorMessage = "Resource not found";
                        } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 401) {
                            errorMessage = message+" Please login again";
                        } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 400) {
                            errorMessage = message+ " Check your inputs";
                        } else if (networkResponse.statusCode == 500) {
                            errorMessage = message+" Something is getting wrong";
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.i("Error", errorMessage);
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("api_token", "gh659gjhvdyudo973823tt9gvjf7i6ric75r76");
                params.put("name", mNameInput.getText().toString());
                params.put("location", mLocationInput.getText().toString());
                params.put("about", mAvatarInput.getText().toString());
                params.put("contact", mContactInput.getText().toString());
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                // file name could found file base or direct access from real path
                // for now just get bitmap data from ImageView
                params.put("avatar", new DataPart("file_avatar.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mAvatarImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));
                params.put("cover", new DataPart("file_cover.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mCoverImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));

                return params;
            }
        };

        VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

For more code you can visit this [url](https://gist.github.com/anggadarkprince/a7c536da091f4b26bb4abf2f92926594#file-volleymultipartrequest-java)